# elements from a list to dataframe names for export

Tags: python, list, dataframe, names

I have a list of names of dataframes

```
list = ['one','two','three','four']
```

and I want to export them:

```
for i in range (0,len(list)):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_path + '//' + 'file'+i+'.xlsx') as writer:
    list[i].to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

it shows this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

basically i need:

```
for i in range (0,len(list)):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_path + '//' + 'file1'.xlsx') as writer:
    one.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

and do it for all element in the list

Comment: How did you get these names of dataframes? It should probably be a `dict` of `name : dataframe`.

Comment: the list of data frames came from a process of identifying what are the missing files in a local folder, after doing it I want to export the data frames as a result of this process, so I came up with a list, but when I set it to go one by one:     for f in missing_file:
            f.to_excel(output_lib + "\\" + f + '.xlsx', index=False), the name of the data frame is getting as a string, cannot find a way to make python read it as the name of the data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a list

```
list_of_dfs = [df0, df1, df2]
```

I created a dictionary with the dataframes (this is the key):

> ```
> UniqueSource = df_raw.Key.unique()
> DataFrameDict = {elem : pd.DataFrame for elem in UniqueSource}
> for key in DataFrameDict.keys():
>     DataFrameDict[key] = df_raw[:][df_raw.Key == key]
> ```

Then I created a list of all files in the path:

```
outlib = os.listdir(output_lib)
outlib_names = [s.replace(".xls","") for s in outlib]
```

And finally by checking each one of the list_of_dfs in the outlib_names, I created a temp dataframe out of the dictionary, it file already exist it will open the file and export the data frame into a sheet, else if the file doesn't exist it will simple just export the data frame as a new file in the path:

> ```
> for f in list_of_dfs:
>         check = (f in outlib_names)
>         if check is True:
>             temp = DataFrameDict[f]
>             with pd.ExcelWriter(output_lib + "\\" + f + '.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
>                 temp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "'" + f "'", index = False)
>         else:
>             temp = DataFrameDict[f]
>             with pd.ExcelWriter(output_lib + "\\" + f + '.xlsx') as writer:
>                 temp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="'" + f + "'", index=False)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You will need the actual dataframe for it to work with .to_excel.  If you just have a string, it will fail because you would be asking for .to_excel to write the string 'one', rather than the dataframe that you want to refer to with the string 'one'.

You can have a list of dataframes and iterate through them, so let's assume you get that list of dataframes.  Let's also assume that you use names '0', '1', '2' that correspond to the index of the dataframe in the list, instead of your original 'one', 'two' ...

You had 1 small bug in the code 'file' + i -- confusing the index i (points to an item in the list) with the item itself.  Also, careful about integers versus strings -- i is an integer, so use str(i) to convert to a string so it can become part of a larger string.

Avoid using 'list' in code because list already means something in Python -- so let's call it 'list_of_dfs'.

Also, range starts with 0 as default, so no need to specify.

So, putting all of that together, you can use either of these:

```
list_of_dfs = [df0, df1, df2]       # assume you get the list of dfs

for i in range(len(list)):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_path + '//' + 'file'+ str(i) +'.xlsx') as writer:
        list_of_dfs[i].to_excel(writer, index=False)


for df in list_of_dfs:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_path + '//' + 'file' + str(list_of_dfs.index(df)) +'.xlsx') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried the way that you suggested and the same error keeps showing: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_excel'"

Comment: You need to have a Pandas dataframe, not just a string.  So if you only have the name of the dataframe, that is merely a string, so that won't work.  Are you starting with a dataframe that you can work with?